# How to add version info to OpenSSL 3.0.2 fips.dll?

Tags: openssl

On Windows, I basically run these batch commands to build the OpenSSL 3.0.2 FIPS module (**fips.dll**):

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A -MT -Z7 no-shared enable-fips
nmake
```

After the build completes, the **fips.dll** has mostly blank details

[image: 3.0.2]

However, during the build process, an **openssl.rc** is created with these details

```
#include <winver.h>

LANGUAGE 0x09,0x01

1 VERSIONINFO
  FILEVERSION 3,0,2,0
  PRODUCTVERSION 3,0,2,0
  FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
  FILEFLAGS 0x01L
#else
  FILEFLAGS 0x00L
#endif
  FILEOS VOS__WINDOWS32
  FILETYPE VFT_APP
  FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            // Required:
            VALUE "CompanyName", "The OpenSSL Project, https://www.openssl.org/\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "OpenSSL application\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "3.0.2\0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "openssl\0"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "openssl\0"
            VALUE "ProductName", "The OpenSSL Toolkit\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "3.0.2\0"
            // Optional:
            //VALUE "Comments", "\0"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright 1998-2022 The OpenSSL Authors. All rights reserved.\0"
            //VALUE "LegalTrademarks", "\0"
            //VALUE "PrivateBuild", "\0"
            //VALUE "SpecialBuild", "\0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 0x4b0
    END
END
```

**Question**

Is there a way to include those **openssl.rc** details into the final **fips.dll**?
Maybe there's an option to some script which can add the version info and hopefully the FIPS file checksum is still valid afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved as follows:

Copy this build generated resource file from

```
C:\OpenSSL-Builds\openssl-3.0.2\apps\openssl-bin-openssl.res
```

to

```
C:\OpenSSL-Builds\OpenSSLoutput-3.0.2\FIPS64\version.res
```

Download and run

> [ResourceHacker.exe](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/#download) -open
> "C:\OpenSSL-Builds\OpenSSLoutput-3.0.2\FIPS64\fips.dll" -save fips.dll
> -action addoverwrite -resource "C:\OpenSSL-Builds\OpenSSLoutput-3.0.2\FIPS64\version.res"

Important, run this command below to regenerate a FIPS module configuration file.  This configuration
file can be used each time a FIPS module is loaded in order to pass data to the FIPS
module self tests.

> openssl.exe fipsinstall -module
> "C:\OpenSSL-Builds\OpenSSLoutput-3.0.2\FIPS64\fips.dll" -out
> "C:\OpenSSL-Builds\OpenSSLoutput-3.0.2\FIPS64\fips.cnf"

The fips.dll should now show the updated version info

[image: openssl3.0.version.info]